# refactoring delegate : Method name expected

Tags: c#, delegates

In [this code example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T583428/how-to-use-new-dragdropbehavior-in-xaf) there is this code snippet:

```
behaviorManager1 = new DevExpress.Utils.Behaviors.BehaviorManager();
behaviorManager1.Attach<DevExpress.Utils.DragDrop.DragDropBehavior>(editor.GridView, behavior => {
    behavior.Properties.AllowDrop = true;
    behavior.Properties.InsertIndicatorVisible = true;
    behavior.Properties.PreviewVisible = true;
    behavior.DragOver += Behavior_DragOver;
    behavior.DragDrop += Behavior_DragDrop;
});
```

For my better understanding, I want refactor the code so that the "behaviour =>" code is not in line.

I tried with:

```
var behaviour = new DragDropBehavior(ctrl.GetType());
behaviour.DragDrop += Behavior_DragDrop;
behaviour.DragOver += Behavior_DragOver;
var action = new Action<DragDropBehavior>(behaviour); // compile error
behaviorManager1.Attach(gridView1, action);
```

However, I get a compile error

> Error CS0149  Method name expected

Comment: What you have above is a Anonymous function. If you do not want to use that Syntax, you have to use a named Function of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between what the initial code does and what your new code does. Initially you're passing in an anonymous function, which when called will set some properties on a provided instance of `DragDropBehavior`. Your new code creates an instance of `DragDropBehavior` explicitly and fills it up.

You're also trying to create an instance of `Action<T>`, which expects a delegate, but instead pass it that newly created object. That's why compiler doesn't like it.

You can still extract that parameter into a variable but it should be typed as `Action<DragDropBehavior>` and all the assignments should be inside an anonymous function:

```
behaviorManager1 = new DevExpress.Utils.Behaviors.BehaviorManager();
Action<DragDropBehavior> behaviorDelegate = behavior => {
    behavior.Properties.AllowDrop = true;
    behavior.Properties.InsertIndicatorVisible = true;
    behavior.Properties.PreviewVisible = true;
    behavior.DragOver += Behavior_DragOver;
    behavior.DragDrop += Behavior_DragDrop;
};
behaviorManager1.Attach<DevExpress.Utils.DragDrop.DragDropBehavior>(editor.GridView, behaviorDelegate);
```